# How can control inside DataTemplate be found in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin

I have a control inside a DataTemplate. When that control executes the Tapped command I want it to be hidden without having to reload the ContentPage.

Page1.xaml

```
<StackLayout x:Name="sss" BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding ....}">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>      
            <Frame x:Name="follower" IsVisible="{Binding Follow}">
                <Label Text="SSSS1" TextColor="#fff" FontSize="11"></Label>
                <Frame.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="follower_Tapped"/>
                </Frame.GestureRecognizers>
            </Frame>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Page1.xaml.cs

```
FeedsViewModel feedsViewModel;
public Page1()
{
    BindingContext = feedsViewModel = new FeedsViewModel(Navigation);
    feedsViewModel.OnAppearing();
}

private void follower_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = "s";
    //Find Control Frame x:Name="follower" to IsVisible False
    .......
}
```

How can I hide the Frame x:Name="follower" control when I follow_Tapped. Can anyone help me with a solution to this problem? Thank you

Comment: you should not directly manipulate the UI of items in a DataTemplate - you should use binding to set their properties instead

Comment: Can you be more specific and clear? Thank you

Comment: `IsVisible` is already bound to the `Follow` property, so just change the value of `Follow` in your model instead of trying to manually modify the UI element

Comment: Thanks, I will try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could set the `IsVisible` property in current Frame.

```
 private void follower_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var frame = sender as Frame;
        frame.IsVisible = false;
    }
```